# Capturing webcam images,videos with C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webcam

Actually i want to access webcam to capture pictures and record videos using C# and .Net.
I have seen many examples in google.But all of them are using COM programming ,which i m not familiar with.I want to know if there is any built in library in .Net framework 4.0 for doing that.There are several opensource libraries for capturing images using C#.But i want to use the built in capabilities of .Net.Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

[XNA](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/iersoy/how-to-use-webcam-in-xna/) from Microsoft ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203940.aspx

EDIT:

Another Lib: http://code.google.com/p/aforge/

Read first answer as sample > [webcam calling in xna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789684/webcam-calling-in-xna)

Comment: Click the xna keyword in the answer. >>XNA<< from Microsoft

Comment: Sir, frankly that code was very difficult to understand.Can u please suggest me how to do it using DirectShow.Net ...

Comment: DirectShow is in Windows SDK. This is too hard than xna. Please look at my updated answer.